# Bootstrap/Brunch difficulty with Phoenix

Tags: heroku, twitter-bootstrap-3, phoenix-framework, brunch

I am trying to compile bootstrap with Brunch in Phoenix.  I have deployed a simple collapse nav to heroku, but the nav button doesn't activate on resize: https://hidden-wildwood-14271.herokuapp.com/test

If you look at the `<head>` in the source code, you'll see this:

    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->`

When these links/scripts are uncommented, this nav bar works just fine (assuming you're doing this from a local/non-https, like heroku in production).  Instead I have to use the Brunch-compiled `css/app.css` and `js/app.js`at the top.  Those file contain exactly the same code as the referenced files in comments (bootstrap css, jquery/bootstrap js).

I'm also getting this error in the console, and have no idea what it means:
`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'web/static/js/app' from '/'`

Also, this is what my `brunch-config` looks like (very little difference from default configuration):

```
exports.config = {
  // See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"

      // To use a separate vendor.js bundle, specify two files path
      // http://brunch.io/docs/config#-files-
      // joinTo: {
      //  "js/app.js": /^(web\/static\/js)/,
      //  "js/vendor.js": /^(web\/static\/vendor)|(deps)/
      // }
      //
      // To change the order of concatenation of files, explicitly mention here
      // order: {
      //   before: [
      //     "web/static/vendor/js/jquery-2.1.1.js",
      //     "web/static/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      //   ]
      // }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css",
      order: {
        after: ["web/static/css/app.css"] // concat app.css last
      }
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js",
      order: {
        before: ["web/static/js/app.js"]
      }
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    // This option sets where we should place non-css and non-js assets in.
    // By default, we set this to "/web/static/assets". Files in this directory
    // will be copied to `paths.public`, which is "priv/static" by default.
    assets: /^(web\/static\/assets)/
  },

  // Phoenix paths configuration
  paths: {
    // Dependencies and current project directories to watch
    watched: [
      "web/static",
      "test/static"
    ],

    // Where to compile files to
    public: "priv/static"
  },

  // Configure your plugins
  plugins: {
    sass: {
      options: {
        // Use includePaths to allow sass to load files outside your tree
        // For example, from node_modules
        //includePaths: ['app/css']
      }
    },
    postcss: {
      processors: [
        require('autoprefixer')(['last 8 versions'])
      ]
    },
    babel: {
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
    }
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true
  }
};
```

Comment: Your Bootstrap javascript isn't being loaded by Brunch. I can't vouch for this code, but Google took me here: https://gist.github.com/eproxus/545618f91983ff302a0a734888e7d01c